# How to create N ActionListener with for loop?

Tags: java, swing, loops, jbutton, actionlistener

I have been created N(unknown SIZE) Jbuttons with for loop and placed them in the frame.
I am trying to display the message "Button number x" by clicking on button number x.
On the second for loop, when I trying to create N ActionListener I have some error.

Error

> Local variable I defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final

Code

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class program extends JFrame{
    final int N = 10;
    final int JUMPS = 210;
    private JButton[] buttons = new JButton[N];

    public program(){
        super("test");
        setLayout(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            buttons[i] = new JButton("" + i);
            buttons[i].setBounds((i % 4) * JUMPS, (i / 4) *JUMPS , 200, 200);
            add(buttons[i]);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            buttons[i].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Button number " + i);
                }
            });
        } 

        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        program mainGUI = new program();
    }
}
```

Did you have any solution for the error?

Comment: Don't use setBounds() to set the size/location of the button. Instead use a `GridLayout`. Let the layout manager do the work for you. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use GridLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html) for more information and working examples.

Comment: Also, there is no need for two loops. Just add the ActionListener to the button when you create the button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Button number " + e.getActionCommand());
```

Comment: (1+) and using this approach you only need to create a single ActionListener that can be shared by all buttons.

Answer (score 1):

You can't reference a local variable `i` inside your `ActionListener` implementation unless `i` is final (or effectively final). But you can just make a final variable and reference that.

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    final int final_i = i;
    buttons[i].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Button number " + final_i);
        }
    });
}
```

And in Java 8 you can do this more consisely:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    final int final_i = i;
    buttons[i].addActionListener(e ->
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Button number " + final_i)
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If anonymous class is created inside any method then all the local variables defined in the method but outside the body of the anonymous class should be made final in case they are needed to be used in anonymous class.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class program extends JFrame{
    final int N = 10;
    final int JUMPS = 210;
    private JButton[] buttons = new JButton[N];

    public program(){
        super("test");
        setLayout(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            buttons[i] = new JButton("" + i);
            buttons[i].setBounds((i % 4) * JUMPS, (i / 4) *JUMPS , 200, 200);
            add(buttons[i]);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        final int buttonNumber = i ;
            buttons[i].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Button number " + buttonNumber);
                }
            });
        } 

        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        program mainGUI = new program();
    }
}
```